# Configuration of website with IIS

Tags: visual-studio, iis

I have a couple of configuration questions:

1. How do I configure the local web site to use IIS. I need to run the web site using IIS server not default visual studio web development server.
2. How do I give the solution name for website.

   For example, normally when you create a web site it will display the website name as:

   `http://localhost/testproject` or `d://....../testproject`

   But I need to display the web site project name as testproject alone

Answer (score 0):

Modify your hosts file to point at your ip address with a dns name for the second bit. Then set up your dns name in a website in iis. When you browse to the dns you will hit your website iis will strip the dns name for it and forward your request to the correct site.

For the first bit its too long winded you will have to read a tutorial..